# How to stop screen from dimming when power cable is unplugged?

Tags: screen, brightness

On HP Pavilion with Ubu 14.04 LTS, screen automatically dims when power cable is unplugged. I sometimes want to have maximum brightness, even when power cable is unplugged, for personal reasons.

How can I do this?
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: This should be a setting in your BIOS. try restarting and pressing ESC repeatingly upon startscreen to access your BIOS and set the options to dim your screen accordingly. Ubuntu does not manage your LCDs brightness level.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the GUI**:

1. Open "System Settings"
2. Under "Personal", click on "Brightness & Lock"
3. To disable dimming, under "Brightness", untick "Dim screen to save power"
4. To re-enable dimming, under "Brightness", tick "Dim screen to save power"

**Using the command line**:

To disable dimming run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
```

To re-enable dimming run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution no longer works. I am leaving my answer here to wait for an authority from Ubuntu community/developer to chip in.**

None of the solutions here worked. I managed to correct this behavior by using [laptop-mode-tools](https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/dim-display-when-switching-to-battery-power-on-ubuntu/) plugin:

1. Install the plugin with `apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`.
2. Set the dim I wished to set to: `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` this should give a value between 1 to 7500. Say I got 3000 in this case.
3. Edit the file `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/lcd-brightness.conf`: I updated the bottom-most settings to the following:

`# Commands to execute to set the brightness on your LCD
    #
    BATT_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 2000"
    LM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 7500"
    NOLM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 3000"
    BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`

4. And lastly, an important step: Plug the adaptor in, then plug it off again. You should see the screen brightness stays the same.

This solution works on Dell Alienware.

Answer (score -3):

SOLVED: click on battery icon at bottom of desktop, where time & date appears. after click go to more options on battery icon, then create your own plan by name PLAN 1 or PLAN 2 as you wish. then set all settings like battery, power and other option to NEVER. then click on next.

Now your laptop screen will not be dim if you unplug the charger.

EnJOY..... RASHID JATOI.